# Get data from Django's raw() query function?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm using a raw query and i'm having trouble finding out how to get the all row data (corresponding each table column). if my input queries having with multiple left join.

Comment: Can you show us the working of some query that you did

Comment: query = select * from tab1 
left join tab2 on tab2.patient_id =tab1.patient_id ,tab3
 left join tab4 on tab4.patient_id =tab3.patient_id

       data = model.objects.raw(query)

now i want to access all column values.

Answer (score 1):

According to me, if I understand the question correctly then the raw() manager method can be used to perform raw SQL queries:

```
 for p in Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person'):
```

According to documentation, this can help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/

For multi-join:

```
  SELECT table.id, other_table.name AS name from table join other_table using (id)
```

and pass that into your table model. Django would then treat the names from other_table as though they were names from table and give your normal table instances. You pass the query to ModelName.objects.raw(query)

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 301, in __get__
    raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist

Comment: @user3016773 More likely that you have something missing. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435096/self-field-rel-to-doesnotexist-when-trying-to-access-user-through-model

Comment: @user3016773 You cannot just copy-paste. You need to understand what you are doing. Your question was too general.